# How come the JButton in my JDialog are not working? Fixed

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, mouseevent, jbutton

This is the constructor for the JDialog View in question:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class AjoutPatient extends JDialog {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private ControleurAjout ajoutControleur;
  private JPanel contentPane;
  private JPanel buttonPane;
  private JButton ajouterButton;
  private JButton annulerButton;

  AjoutPatient() {
      init();

      //Creation du controleur
      ajoutControleur = new ControleurAjout(this);

      //Ajout de listeners sur les composantes
      ajouterButton.addActionListener(ajoutControleur);
      annulerButton.addActionListener(ajoutControleur);

      //Reglage de visibilite et modal
      setModal(true);
      setVisible(true);
  }

  private void init(){
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      setTitle("Test JDialog");
      //Ajout panel principal
      contentPane = new JPanel();
      contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setContentPane(contentPane);
      contentPane.setLayout(null);

      //Panel des bouton ajouter et annuler
      buttonPane = new JPanel();
      buttonPane.setBounds(5, 322, 304, 42);
      contentPane.add(buttonPane);
      buttonPane.setLayout(null);

      //Boutons ajouter et annuler
      ajouterButton = new JButton("Ajouter");
      ajouterButton.setBounds(130, 11, 81, 23);
      buttonPane.add(ajouterButton);
      annulerButton = new JButton("Annuler");
      annulerButton.setBounds(213, 11, 81, 23);
      buttonPane.add(annulerButton);
  }

  /*
   * Getters
   */
  public JButton getAjouterButton(){
      return ajouterButton;
  }

  public JButton getAnnulerButton(){
      return annulerButton;
  }
}
```

Then the JDialog controller:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class ControleurAjout implements ActionListener {

  private AjoutPatient vue;

  ControleurAjout(AjoutPatient ajout){
      vue = ajout;      
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == vue.getAjouterButton()){
            vue.dispose();
        }
    }else if(e.getSource() == vue.getAnnulerButton()){
            vue.dispose();
    }
  }

  public JButton getAjouterButton(){
      return ajouterButton;
  }

  public JButton getAnnulerButton(){
      return annulerButton;
  }
}
```

This is the main JFrame controller:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class ControleurRecherche implements ActionListener {

  private FenetreRecherche vue;

  ControleurRecherche(FenetreRecherche recherche){
      vue = recherche;
  }

  //Ecouteurs d'evenement
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == vue.getAjouterButton()){
        ajout = new AjoutPatient();
        //modele.ajouterPatient(ajout);
    }else if(e.getSource() == vue.getFermerButton()){
            System.exit(0);
    } 
}
```

This is the main JFrame method:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FenetreRecherche extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private ControleurRecherche rechControleur;
  private JPanel contentPane;
  private JPanel buttonPane;
  private JButton ajouterButton;
  private JButton fermerButton;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    FenetreRecherche recherche = new FenetreRecherche();
    recherche.setVisible(true);

  }

  FenetreRecherche() {
      init();
      //Creation du controlleur
      rechControleur = new ControleurRecherche(this);
      //Ajout de listeners sur les composantes
      ajouterButton.addActionListener(rechControleur);
      fermerButton.addActionListener(rechControleur);
  }

    //Initialiser le GUI
    private void init(){

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Test");
    setResizable(false);
    setBounds(100, 100, 600, 320);

    //Panel de contenu de la fenetre
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 0));

    //Panel des boutons menu
    buttonPane = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout flowButtonPane = (FlowLayout) buttonPane.getLayout();
    flowButtonPane.setVgap(20);
    flowButtonPane.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
    contentPane.add(buttonPane);

    //Boutons menu
    ajouterButton = new JButton("Ajouter");
    buttonPane.add(ajouterButton);
    fermerButton = new JButton("Fermer");
    buttonPane.add(fermerButton);       
  }
  /*
   * Getters
   */
  public JButton getAjouterButton(){
      return ajouterButton;
  }
  public JButton getFermerButton(){
      return fermerButton;
  }

}
```

With all that I hope the problem can be fixed without an issue.
Just needed to change the setVisible(true) for JDialog at the end of the constructor. Edited in order to have the final working version up here.

Comment: `JButton` emits [`ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html). So you need [`ActionListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to catch it.

Comment: @PM77-1, that still doesn't work, it might have to do with the JFrame controller code, which I'll add in a moment, because I used the MousePressed event to open the JDialog, that's also the reason of my confusion.

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer, ok hold on, this will take a short while since my GUI has too much unnecessary code for this issue, so I'll reformat it so it can be executed.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, It's done, this should be runnable.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: After getting your code to compile, I removed the `setLayout(null)` elements from your `AjoutPatient` `init` method and finally got the buttons to appear and they do work just fine...see previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used the MousePressed event to open the JDialog

Don't use a MouseListener~

You need to use an ActionListener. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Can you clarify why it's better to use ActionListener other than MouseListener aside from it's wider use? I'll change my code to use the ActionListener and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: `other than MouseListener aside from it's wider use?` - is that not a good enough reason? Why would you try to reinvent the wheel when you know the common approach?. Keep your code simple so others will understand it and don't do crazy things just because you want to! Anyway, a button click is defined as a mousePressed and mouseReleased on the same button. This is not easily supported with a MouseListener because even if the user moves the mouse 1 pixel the mouseClicked event will not be generated.

Comment: because I use another method that needs the mouse pressed at least so I thought I'd save from using one method.
It still didn't work either, it really seems like the JDialog I open doesn't instantiate any of the listeners... That's what I'll have to work on, unless if you can help me with this please.

Comment: @Ido013 a button may be triggered by pressing it with the mouse, pressing the space bar/enter key while the button is focused or programmatically or, if set, via the nemonic shortcut key  . The MouseListener will only catch one of these use cases, where as the ActionListener will catch all of them. ActionListener abstracts the events by which the button can be actives into a single, uniform interface.

Comment: @Ido013: and if you try to disable the button with `.setEnabled(false)`, do you think that your MouseListener will be disabled as the user would expect? Nope, it still would function, leading to a very confusing GUI. Here's another voice telling you -- use the right tool for the job, the ActionListener.